# How to modify Count(*) result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need to modify the Count result.

Input Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<**TableName**>' 
 AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('**Column1Name**','**Column2Name**')
```

Output:
2

My requirement is, result should be '1' if both the columns get[image] present in table.

Could some one help me out here with simple solution.

Comment: Clarify your question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT 1 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<**TableName**>' AND 
      COLUMN_NAME IN ('**Column1Name**','**Column2Name**')
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

You have to ensure that `HAVING COUNT(*) = 2` should have exact same count value defined with `IN` clause argument.

For example :

If `COLUMN_NAME IN ('**Column1Name**','**Column2Name**', '**Column3Name**')`, so `HAVING` clause would be `HAVING COUNT(*) = 3`.

Comment: I thought he meant something like `Count >= 1` return `1` and `Count = 0` return `0` - basically `bool` for does any of those column exist.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing having clause.

```
SELECT 1 COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<**TableName**>' 
 AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('**Column1Name**','**Column2Name**') having count(*)=2

SELECT case when count(*)=2 then 1 else 0 end COLUMN_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<**TableName**>' 
     AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('**Column1Name**','**Column2Name**') having count(*)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `1` or `0`, you can use `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<**TableName**>' AND
      COLUMN_NAME IN ('**Column1Name**','**Column2Name**');
```